# Ruby on Rails - Multi-line Command and reversing a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

This will probably seem like a very easy fix to a dumb question but I'm asking here to prevent any further mistakes in my project. I'm currently following Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and I came across a command in the .pdf that I didn't quite understand how to interpret and I believe I messed up when entering it. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

I put both questions into one screenshot and labeled them as one and two.
Part 1 shows what the .pdf had me enter into the console and I wasn't sure how to do that correctly. Part 2 shows how I attempted it and I was wondering if I could reverse that mistake to enter it in correctly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You entered the first line correctly: `rails...`. The second line `activation_digest...` can be just entered as:

```
activation_digest...
```

the `>` character denotes a newline that you do not enter. It's automatically created with the `\` newline character from the line prior. So in summary:

```
//Don't enter this line. You already typed it in.
$ rails generate migration add_activation_to_users
//Type in this line
$ activation_digest:string...blahblah
```